# how to hide password when launching executable

Tags: c, fork

I have two executables: ELF_A and ELF_B (both coded in C)

ELF_B requires a password upon start.

I added the same password for ELF_A on start and it starts ELF_B using fork  sending the password as argument.

Everything works fine except the security (it is visible with ps)

Is there any way to avoid sending the password to ELF_B as argument?
Session, oauth, something?

Comment: As a hack, `ELF_B` could write over his `argv` after getting the password.

Comment: done that already but I'm still worried about the security

Answer (score 0):

Yes: pipes, network, or any other [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) mechanism. 
But doing that alone still doesn't add to the security; you'll have to account for the middleman.